# I need a macro to evaluate data in excel while counting by 10

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in 3 columns lets call them A, B, and C. All three columns are exclusively numbers. I need to look at column A and find all numbers that are between X-Y. For example I need all numbers between 95-104, these numbers can all be grouped as 100, I then need the next 10 so 105-114 and all those numbers can be group 110. Once I have the numbers in the group I need to find the average of group 100 in columns B and C. My final chart will read column A group, then B will be average of that group and C will be the other column average.

Comment: Okay, you have a nice target! What have you done so far to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple loop.

```
with TAB1
for i = 1 to .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
if cells(i,1) > Y and cells(i,1) < X then _
.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else .EntireRow.Hidden = False
next
```

Then you can use subtotal excel function for average. Not tested it is little help I cant run excel on my mobile =)